# Java send mail automatically with local mail client

Tags: java, email

From within a java program I want to send a mail via the local mail client of the user automatically.

I use the following code to open up the client and fill in the required fields but how do I send it now automatically without any user interaction?

```
    private void sendMail() throws MessagingException {
    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().mail(new URI("mailto:abc@def.com?subject=someSubject&cc=aa@bb.cc,dd@dd.ds&bcc=x@y.zz&body=someBodyText"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Basically I want to send mails that don't leave the network of the company.

Comment: There is no API which works with every mail client, so the best option is to use [Java Mail API](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) and send the mails directly.

Comment: I have already been toying around with the Java Mail API and my main issue is that I don't know which mailserver will be running on the client machines. What values do I use for the following property: mail.smtp.host. I know that the client will be in a local network containing a mailserver but I don't know its "name".

Answer (score 1):

The answer is [Java Mail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html).

Basically, you need a mail account (usually username+password), you also need the mail SP's SMTP server address, which is usually on their website.

Comment: The application will be running at various complettly independent networks. All I know is that there will be a mailserver for each of the networks but I don't know its address. Any easy way to retrieve this information, maybe from the registry?

Comment: You need to know more about those networks, don't assume their configurations. Ask the administrator, establish agreements on how your programs are going to interact with the environment.

Comment: Well if there is no way to finde it out I will have to ask the user to provide this information. I was hoping to somehow extract this information from the mail client of the user.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to deal with outlook at least, following this guide: [Vogella, Eclipse-Microsoft Integration](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseMicrosoftIntegration/article.html)

Basically I'm using the OleClientSite class to invoke outlook. Then I'm using the oleAutomation class to send the mail.

Code snippet:

```
            Shell shell = new Shell(Display.getDefault());
            OleFrame frame = new OleFrame(shell, SWT.NONE);
            // This should start outlook if it is not running yet
            OleClientSite site = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "OVCtl.OVCtl");
            site.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE);
            // Now get the outlook application
            OleClientSite site2 = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE,
                "Outlook.Application");
            OleAutomation outlook = new OleAutomation(site2);
            // 
            OleAutomation mail = invoke(outlook, "CreateItem", 0 /* Mail item */)
                .getAutomation();
            setProperty(mail, "To", "aav@gmail.com"); /*
                                   * Empty but could also be
                                   * predefined
                                   */

            setProperty(mail, "Bcc", "test@gmail.com"); /*
                                   * Empty but could also be
                                   * predefined
                                   */

            setProperty(mail, "BodyFormat", 2 /* HTML */);
            setProperty(mail, "Subject", "Top News for you");
            setProperty(mail, "HtmlBody",
                "<html>Hello<p>, please find some infos here.</html>");

            invoke(mail, "Send" /* or "Send" */);
```