# How to send outlook mail from java program , without using SMTP

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, smtp

Thanks in advance for your help and support.

Using the below code i am able to open my outlook and specifying TO, CC Subject and Mail Body, but i am unable to send the email automatically, Kindly help on this.

```
package com.emailtrigger;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class sendMail
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException
    {
        String subject="Email Testing through Code";
        String body="This is testing purpose";
        String cc="AAA@abc.com";

        try {
           Desktop.getDesktop().mail( new URI( "mailto:abc@ddd.com?subject="+subject+"&cc="+cc+"&body="+body) );


        } 
        catch ( IOException ex )
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will print error then it is : `Illegal character in opaque part`.

You should not provide space between values.[Ref](https://dzone.com/articles/simple-way-sending-emails-java)

All values should be URL-encoded `(e.g. space becomes %20)` 
[How to URL encode](https://www.urlencoder.org/)

Your code in above scenario -

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException  {
             String subject="Email%20Testing%20through%20Code";
             String body="This%20is%20testing%20purpose";
             String cc="AAA@abc.com";

             try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().mail( new URI( "mailto:abc@ddd.com?subject="+subject+"&cc="+cc+"&body="+body) );
             } 
            catch ( IOException ex ) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: this was not my question, i was expecting how to sent the emali?

Comment: You can't send email automatically using above approach. there is another question related to this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17472659/7505731